# Build symfony docker container without DB

Tags: php, symfony, continuous-integration

I have an symfony application, and i want to create docker container, that contains all needed files. The purpose is to spin up/down containers for scaling, without any other deploying processes. Just with given DB connection.

Building means, pretty much just `git clone` and running `composer install`, but some of symfony's post install scripts fail without configured DB.

`Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets`

Can i not run these scripts when i'm building container? Or what the proper way to do symfony deployment?

---

Using Symfony 3.2, Doctrine2, PHP 7.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to build a container without running the db script is by not running there scripts in the build,

Here is the one we use in production for api-platform:

```
    FROM php:7.1-fpm-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .persistent-deps \
        git \
        icu-libs \
        zlib \
        postgresql-client

ENV APCU_VERSION 5.1.8

RUN set -xe \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        $PHPIZE_DEPS \
        icu-dev \
        zlib-dev \
        postgresql-dev \
        sqlite-dev \
        pcre-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        intl \
        mbstring \
        pdo_mysql \
        pdo_pgsql \
        pdo \
        pgsql \
        zip \
        pdo_sqlite \
    && pecl install \
        apcu-${APCU_VERSION} \
    && docker-php-ext-enable --ini-name 20-apcu.ini apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-enable --ini-name 05-opcache.ini opcache \
    && apk del .build-deps

COPY docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

COPY docker/php/install-composer.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-app-install-composer

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-app-install-composer

RUN set -xe \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .fetch-deps \
        openssl \
    && docker-app-install-composer \
    && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer \
    && apk del .fetch-deps


ARG SYMFONY_ENV=dev
ENV SYMFONY_ENV=dev
RUN if [ "$SYMFONY_ENV" -ne "dev" ]; then \
        sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_enable=1' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini && \
        sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini && \
        sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_autostart=0' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini && \
        sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_connect_back=1 ' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini && \
        sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_port=9001' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini && \
        sed -i '1 a xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug_remote.log' /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini && \
        pecl install \
                xdebug \
           && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug; \
    fi;

# https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-allow-superuser
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1

WORKDIR /srv/quotatis

COPY composer.json ./
COPY composer.lock ./

RUN mkdir -p \
        var/cache \
        var/logs \
        var/sessions \
    && composer global require "hirak/prestissimo:^0.3" --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-suggest -o -a \
    && composer install --prefer-dist --no-dev --no-autoloader --no-scripts --no-progress --no-suggest \
    && composer clear-cache \
# Permissions hack because setfacl does not work on Mac and Windows
    && chown -R www-data var

COPY app app/
COPY bin bin/
COPY src src/
COPY web web/
COPY etc etc/

RUN composer dump-autoload --optimize --classmap-authoritative --no-dev

COPY docker/php/start.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-app-start

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-app-start

CMD ["docker-app-start"]
```

You could see the whole stack (nginx + fpm + varnish on [github](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform))

The line that you need in here is this one

```
composer install --prefer-dist --no-dev --no-autoloader --no-scripts --no-progress --no-suggest
```